# xsel < /tmp/xselection not working in script

Tags: shell, xorg, vim, utilities, clipboard

I'm trying to use the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Edit xselection in gvim
xsel > /tmp/xselection
gvim /tmp/xselection
xsel < /tmp/xselection
```

But the final line does not seem to be correctly loading the file into xselection. If I run that line immediately after calling the script it succeeds. I can't understand why. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the fact that the call to gvim does not block until you exit gvim, it returns immediately.  So the `xsel < /tmp/xselection` is processing the file before you edit it.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up incorporating information from both/all three answers to generate the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Edit xselection in gvim

xsel > /tmp/xselection
gvim -f /tmp/xselection
xsel -i < /tmp/xselection
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `-i` option. (`-o` is the default)

```
xsel -i </tmp/xselection
# -o, --output   write the selection to standard output.  
# -i, --input   read standard input into the selection.*
```

These optons work on the X *primary* selection (not the clipboard), so you need to center-click to see the resullt.  I've tested it with a pause before the final command. This allowed me to manually select some other text before the final command executed. The I center-clicked and it worked fine... and it works without the delay.

However testing it without the delay doesn't prove much, becaust the original selection is still selected... and, of course, if you select something else in the meantime, you will lose the script's primary selection.

Perhaps your issue is a combination of both the `-i` option, and Paul Tomblin's answer about the way `gvim` detaches from the script process.

Comment: No, you don't need `-i` here: if stdin is not a terminal, xsel sets the selection from standard input. That's not to say that explicitly passing `-i` isn't a good idea, but it can't be the source of the problem.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks for pointing that out; I wasn't aware of that syntax. I've now re-read the *man page*, and yes, it does (seem to) state that no options are needed, but that is not what I experience in all situations (on my test Ubuntu system). Those *stdin/out* rules only apply when the script is run from the terminal. When the script is launched via the "Run Application" dialog, or via a shortcut-key, it *definitely needs* the `-i` option. Now I  understand why I was getting strange results (until I used `-i`). I've added another answer which deals with both issues: *options* and *detaching*.

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was getting a bit crowded and was incomplete (and had only one edit-itteration left). So here is an amended answer which includes both ideas... *options* and *detaching*.

As I've mentioned in a follow-up commen to Giles comment (previous answer), the `-i` option is definitely needed in some situations (on the test Ubuntu system).. so `-i` and `-o` are used here.

Because 'gvim' detaches from the script's process, it doesn't wait, and the next command is executed immediately. (Paul Tomblin has already pointed thos out in hes answer).

You can't use bash's `wait` command, as it only works for *child processes*. As workaround, you can set up a loop which waits for the *non-child* process to terminate. This works for an editor which starts with a new process each time (as 'gvim' does in this case).

Here is the modified script

```
xsel -o >/tmp/xselection

gvim /tmp/xselection 2>/dev/null
pid=$(pgrep -n "gvim")  # get gvim's pid and wait
while kill -0 "$pid" 2>/dev/null; do sleep 0.5; done

xsel -i </tmp/xselection
```

The above assumes that gvim` pid is already established by the time control is passed back to the script. If, under a high system load, the pid hasn't been established upon executing the next command, then this method of waiting for gvim should work.

```
xsel -o >/tmp/xselection

pre=$(pgrep -n gvim)    # get previous gvim pid
gvim /tmp/xselection 2>/dev/null
while pid=$(pgrep -n "gvim"); [[ "$pid" == "$pre" ]]; do sleep .1; done
while kill -0 "$pid" 2>/dev/null; do sleep 0.5; done

xsel -i </tmp/xselection
```

Comment: I found gvim also has a flag -f that makes it stay in the foreground, which keeps the script a little simpler. Thank you for both of your answers though!